# Terminator transparency not showing other opened windows but only wallpaper

Tags: 11.10, transparency, terminator

Terminator transparency not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10. At zero slider it is  becoming completely black and at max slider its showing wallpaper background rather than background containing other opened windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use real compositing for that. What configuration do you have? If you have a graphics card, installing the [Additional Drivers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/) will solve the problem.